# Leaked shared memory even though it is closed at shutdown

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, shared-memory

Two simple scripts using shared memory / [shared memory dict](https://github.com/luizalabs/shared-memory-dict):

- test2.py is executed first (python3 test2.py)
- test1.py is executed afterwards and should be able to run again and again

test2.py waits until test1.py stores some information into the shared memory, prints it and empties the shared memory, waiting again for some information to be stored

test1.py stores a string, given to the script as startup-parameter, into the shared memory and ends.

It does not matter if test1.py closes the shared memory or not, there is always an **error** (see output of test1.py).
When test1.py is executed again, test2.py always prints "sm is empty". But why? It does not matter either if test1.py closes the shared memory object or not.

Thank you for any solutions!

**test1.py**

```
import sys
import time
import atexit

from shared_memory_dict import SharedMemoryDict

sm = SharedMemoryDict(name='shared', size=1024)


try:
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        
        str = sys.argv[1]       
        sm["str"] = str     
        print("finished")
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    
    print("execute cleanup on KeyboardInterrupt")   
    sm.shm.close()  
    print("closed")



def on_exit():
    
    print("execute cleanup on_exit")    
    sm.shm.close()  
    print("closed")

atexit.register(on_exit)
```

*Console output:*

```
finished
execute cleanup on_exit
closed

/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

**test2.py**

```
import sys
import time
import atexit

from shared_memory_dict import SharedMemoryDict


sm = SharedMemoryDict(name='shared', size=1024)

sm["str"] = ""


try:
    
    while(True):
        
        if sm["str"] == "":
            print("sm is empty")
        else:
            print("sm is not empty: ", sm["str"])           
            
            sm["str"] = ""          
            print("sm is empty again")      
        
        time.sleep(1)
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    
    print("exit program")
    
    sm.shm.close()
    sm.shm.unlink()
    
    print("closed and unlinked")


def on_exit():
    
    print("execute cleanup on exit")
    
    sm.shm.close()
    sm.shm.unlink()

atexit.register(on_exit)
```

(Not) Closing the shared memory objects does not change anything - either via atexit or at the end of the script / after breaking the loop in test2.py